# "TypeError: data type not understood" from NumPy on Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ctypes

I'm porting a C++ array of structs to NumPy.

The C++ code looks like that:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

someFunction(SomeStruct** ptr, int* lenOfArr);
```

The code in Python looks like that:

```
class SomeStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_int), ('y', c_int)]

ptr, lenOfArr = pointer(SomeStruct()), c_int()
myDLL.someFunction(byref(ptr), byref(lenOfArr))
array = SomeStruct * lenOfArr.value
addr = addressof(ptr.contents)
dt = np.dtype([("x", np.intc), ("y", np.intc)])
antPairs = np.frombuffer(array.from_address(addr), dt)
```

It works great on Python 3, but on Python 2.7 I get `TypeError: data type not understood` when creating `dt`.

I tried to change `np.intc` when assigning to `dt` to a bunch of other numpy's data types. but it was unsuccessful (same error).